# Por que o programa funciona apesar da invasão de memória no vetor s?

Tags: c, array, gerenciamento-de-memória

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 char s[2];
 int i;
 printf("Entre com os caracteres\n");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 s[i]=getche();
 printf("\n\n");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 printf("%c ", s[i]);
 printf("\n\n");
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cada compilador pode, dependendo da arquitetura da máquina, deixar algum(ns) byte(s) não alocado(s)/preenchido(s) para otimizar o alinhamento das variáveis alocadas. A linguagem C considera que o programador sabe o que está fazendo e não coíbe, por exemplo, o extravasamento de memória. Pode ser que você dê sorte e o extravasamento do array caia nestes bytes não utilizados, mas pode dar azar e cair em uma área de memória utilizada por outra variável.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 1):

Nem analisei o código para ver o problema exato, mas o que as pessoas precisam ter em mente que C é uma linguagem permissiva, ela deixa quase tudo acontecer, e é problema do programador se cuidar para não dar problema. Alguns compiladores até possuem opções pra lidar melhor com certas situações, as bibliotecas ajudam um pouco não acontecer coisas terríveis quando usa suas funções, tem ferramentas externas, mas o programador deve saber o que está fazendo e estar no controle de tudo. Esta é a maior vantagem de C, por isso ela é rápido e flexível, mas cobra o preço.

De uma certa forma ela boa porque gera problemas graves e faz tanto as pessoas que não se dão bem com programação se afastarem dela como faz elas perceberem que nem tudo que funciona está certo. Quando a pessoa entende isso e coloca um foco forte no seu trabalho sempre considerando isso ela acaba se tornando profissional com P maiúsculo.

As linguagens que são permissivas em coisas que não causam problemas tão graves viciam o "programador" em fazer funcionar, mesmo que esteja errado.

C não tem controles robustos de memória, você aloca um *buffer* e é problema seu gerenciá-lo. Se fizer besteira azar o seu. E se nada mais causar problema parece que está certo, e funciona, não dá erro, mas ou dá um resultado inesperado ou está tudo certo por coincidência. Em exercícios é muito comum ficar certo por coincidência afinal o código é tão simples que não gera conflito, e é exatamente o que aconteceu neste código, ele é tão pequeno que não teve oportunidade sequer de corromper a memória, mas comece fazer mais alguma coisa e acontecerá.

A memória está lá para você usar com liberdade. Grandes poderes, grandes responsabilidades. Você colocou em uma área não declarada, o compilador deixa, se você não usar a área ultrapassada, ok, se declarar outra coisa ali e usar vai ter perda de dados.

Tecnicamente não houve invasão de memória porque C tem toda memórias do processo à sua disposição, conceitualmente sim, houve invasão, e conceitos consertamos nós fazendo do jeito certo.

Answer (score 1):

O @Maniero já explicou o problema em si, mas eu quero na minha resposta focar o seu código e conclusão.

Você começa dizendo:

> Por que o programa funciona apesar da invasão de memória no vetor s?

Mas eu digo-lhe que essa conclusão de ter funcionado foi precipitada e não corresponde à realidade. Ora veja a execução do código no [online C compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/r1luAUJYLB).

Repare como eu entrei com 4 carateres:

```
a
b
c
d
```

E a saída foi:

```
a b
```

Aproveitei e coloquei um `print` da variável `i` após o primeiro `for`, que mostra:

```
Valor de i depois do for: 100
```

Como o vetor `s` e a variável `i` estão seguidas em memoria, o primeiro valor lido fora de `s`, na posição `2`, acertou na variável `i`, e alterou o seu valor para `100` que é o código ASCII da letra `c` e fez com que o `for` terminasse no terceiro elemento e não no quarto. Se fosse utilizar o valor de `i` antes do segundo `for` já lhe ia dar resultados inesperados. Apesar de ter colocado os 4 carateres só vê dois efetivamente na saída.

Concluindo: A linguagem C não lhe impede de escrever em memoria que não lhe pertence, e se o fizer vai ter comportamento indefinido, ou seja, qualquer coisa pode acontecer. E nem mesmo neste exemplo pequeno funcionou como esperava por isso imagine em programas bem mais extensos e complexos.